# How to select a default tab upon page load with HTML navigation tabs

Tags: html, tabs, navigation

here's the link to the code.

[HTML Navigation Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators_grid)

And the link to some [Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp)
(last example)

I'm looking to make it so by default the first tab is selected upon page load and if possible change the active tabs text color.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To select the first tab by default :** 
You can set the display property of div of first tab as block and for all other tabs as none.(`<div id="London" class="w3-container city" style="display:block">`) So whenever the page loads,the contents of the first tab will always be visible.And you can accordingly change the display property on click of other tabs which is already achieved in the code.

**Change active tabs text color :**
On click of a particular add you can add CSS Color to it which has the color rule specified in it using Javascript.

Please let me know in comments if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks, the first tab opens by default now, however the line that appears under the title of the tab to let you know which tab is selected doesn't light up. I'm not sure what CSS to use to make the active text color change, I'd also like to figure out how to use a hex color for the tab highlighter. The code uses w3-border-orange.

Comment: @Veiss - > It's actually w3-border-red in the code. And this is a CSS class which is defined in the w3.css stylesheet which is included in the code like this :  (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`) . You can check this link for more details on the stylesheet included in the code to get details for any other class that you don't understand : [ https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css ]

Comment: @Veiss - > **Changing the color of the line that appears :** - You must have observed that the line is because of the CSS Class ->  w3-bottombar(border-bottom : 6px solid #ccc).  So if you want the color of the particular active tab to change you can just another class on click of the tab. In the code they have added CSS class - w3-border-red (border-color: #e91e63!important;). So whatever hex color you want , you can just specify it in the class. I hope this helps. If it does, please accept this as an answer to your question.

Comment: What's the best way to edit that stylesheet? I was thinking of just duplicating it with a different name and hosting it on my website somewhere then changing the link rel to the link of the new stylesheet. I haven't been able to upload the CSS file yet due to some FTP permissions issue or something.  I also tried creating a child theme and putting .w3-orange,.w3-hover-orange:hover{color:#ce6905!important;background-color:#ce6905!important} in it, but that didn't change, thinking because the w3 stylesheet is taking priority over the custom CSS in the child theme.

Comment: I'm also not sure how to add a class to an active tab. That'd be part of the script area of the code right?  Thanks for your help, I'll be formally learning CSS and HTML soon!

Comment: @Veiss : Yes it has to be written in the javascript code. For the link you posted this code is responsible for changing the color : `evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red"; `             Here, the currentTarget is the <a> tag clicked. First Element Child is the corresponding clicked tab with the country name. And through the code,you then change the border color to red. Hope this helps.

Comment: After reading more I found a similar solution that works a little better, but it needs a couple changes as well. 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pexyoe

How could you make it so the currently selected tab stays highlighted with the colored border below instead of moving back to the first tab when you hover off?

Would also like to make the border move across the second row of tabs like it does the first row but under the bottom tabs.

Comment: @Veiss - Can you please post that as a question? We are having a long discussion in comments on different things. And also if this answer helped you,can you please accept it so that others can refer it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need in html for the first tab:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding w3-border-red">London</div>
    </a>
```

and

```
<div id="London" class="w3-container city" style="display:block">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>
```

If you want to change the color of current active tab:

```
.w3-border-red, .w3-hover-border-red:hover {
    border-color: #e91e63!important;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: i want this to work with ontouchend event instead of onclick which doesnt work